# tkinter open blank window

Tags: python, tkinter

python programming as a hobby and passion, I think I'm creating something beyond my possibilities but I would like to learn as much as possible so...

Given the following scripts, why is the window empty when I access the second script?

main script

```
import pandas
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import login
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import richiesta_strumentario
import schede_tecniche

class MainPage(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Richiesta Strumentario")
        self.wm_geometry("300x300")
        self.update()
    
        """immagine pagina"""
        menu_image = Image.open(globus_image)
        menu_image = menu_image.resize((self.winfo_width()-10,int(self.winfo_height()/2)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        menu_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(menu_image)

        label1 = tk.Label(image=menu_image)
        label1.image = menu_image
        label1.place(x= 2, y = 0)

        """script"""
        benvenuto_label = tk.Label(self, text=f"Benvenuto, {data[0]}")
        benvenuto_label.place(x=10, y=150)


        rich_strum_button = tk.Button(self, text='Richiesta\nStrumentario', height=5, width=19)
        rich_strum_button.config(command=lambda: richiesta_strumentario.RichStrum())
        rich_strum_button.place(x=5, y=180)
        visual_pdf_button = tk.Button(self, text='Visualizza\nSchede Tecniche', height=5, width=18)
        visual_pdf_button.config(command=lambda: schede_tecniche.SchedaTecnica())
        visual_pdf_button.place(x=157, y=180)

        exit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Exit', width=40, height=1, command=lambda: self.quit())
        exit_button.place(x=5, y=270)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """con = sqlite3.connect("user_db.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(name, surname, email, password, azienda)")
    con.close()"""
    """Login().mainloop()"""#utilizzare questo per script finale
    """data = Login.data"""#utilizzare questo per script finale
    data = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test"]
    MainPage().mainloop()
```

second script(blank window problem)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

class ShowPdf(pdf.ShowPdf):

    def goto(self, page):
        try:
            self.text.see(self.img_object_li[page - 1])
        except IndexError:
            if self.img_object_li:
                self.text.see(self.img_object_li[-1])



class SchedaTecnica(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("870x600")
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.focus_force()

        def show_pdf(*args):
            for widget in pdfframe.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()

            pdf.ShowPdf.img_object_li.clear()
            file = listbox_pdffile.get(tk.ANCHOR)
            pdfview_frame = pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(pdfframe, pdf_location=f"{path_cartella_pdf}{file}.pdf",
                                               width=80, height=50)
            pdfview_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)


        pdf_files = []

        for file in os.listdir(path_cartella_pdf):
            if file.endswith('.pdf') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_cartella_pdf, file)):
                pdf_files.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])

        var = tk.Variable(value=pdf_files)
        listbox_pdffile = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=var, width=30, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
        scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        listbox_pdffile.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        listbox_pdffile.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', show_pdf)

        #quit_window = tk.Button(self, text='QUIT', command=lambda: self.destroy()).place(x=200, y=3)

        pdfframe = tk.Frame(self, width=80, height=50)
        pdfframe.pack()
```

i need to add detail or i cannot post this so.. that is a program where i have multiple script: login, main page, strum_request, and pdf file viewer... for now i only scripted login, main page and viewer and i think i'm going to have the same problem between mainpage-viewer on strum_request.

Login and MainPage do not have problems. I log-in and then MainPage shows up destroying Login window but retaining all data

Comment: Don't use `tk.Tk` for child windows, use `tk.Toplevel` instead.

Comment: You need to change the line `tk.Tk.__init__(...)` to `tk.Toplevel.__init__(...)` as well.  It is recommended to use `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` instead. Note also that `tkPDFViewer` is no longer supported by the new `PyMuPDF` module which is used by `tkPDFViewer` due to API changes.